# Minecraft Plugin Coding: Command won't change argument int

Tags: java, plugins, arguments, minecraft

So I'm coding a Minecraft plugin, I'm pretty new to this. 
Here's my code:

```
public class ItemGiver extends JavaPlugin {

public int time;
int show = time / 1200;

// Divide by mins by 1200 for ticks
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    getLogger().info("ItemGiver enabled.");
    timer();

}
@Override
public void onDisable() {

}





public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {


    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bonustime") && sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if(args.length == 1) {

        if(player.hasPermission("bonus.set") || player.isOp()) {

                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "[Bonus] The bonus delay has been set to " + show + " minute(s)!");
                time = Integer.parseInt(args[0].trim()) * 1200;
                return true;

                }

        }
        if(args.length != 1) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Incorrect Syntax.");
        }


        } 







    return false;

}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void timer()
{

    this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask(this,new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            for(Player player : Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers())
            {

               player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COBBLESTONE, 32));
               player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_INGOT, 1));
               player.giveExpLevels(2);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "[Bonus] You have received your bonus! Next bonus in " + show + " minutes!" );
            }
        }
    }
    , time, time);
}
```

}

The problem is in the `onCommand` boolean, where I am trying to make a changeable time to delay each "bonus giving", `time = Interger.parseInt(arg[0].trim());` seems to not actually change the value of time? Sorry, may seem like a dumb question.

Comment: Are you expecting the value of `show` to change when you change `time`? Assignments don't work that way. As it stands, it gets initialized to zero (because `time` is initialized to zero, and zero divided by 1200 is still zero) and stays that way.

Comment: I was.. I was expecting both time and show to change. How do I well, uninitialize it from zero? Or is there a way to do so? Once again sorry, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Edit your previous question instead of creating a new one with close to same info

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the value of `show` is calculated once, with the initial value of time. You should update the value of `show` when you update time if you want the value of `show` to be the amount of minutes that the timer represents.

Secondly, the time that you pass to the bukkit runnable is final, where the bukkit runnable schedules it to the original number that you gave it, and updating the `time` variable wont change the interval of the bukkit runnable.

The solution to changing the interval of the bukkit runnable when the time changes is to store a global `BukkitRunnable` variable. In order to do this, you would have to move from the deprecated `getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask()` to the newer `new BukkitRunnable()` method as shown in this tutorial: http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming#Anonymous_BukkitRunnable_Example

What you would then want to do is construct the bukkit runnable once, and store it as a global variable. Every time you update the time, you need to cancel the global bukkit runnable with `runnable.cancel()` then schedule it to run again with `runnable.runTaskTimerAsynchronously()` using the new `time` variable that you just calculated.

Just a tip, you shouldn't be scheduling an asynchronous task (on another thread) for a task that updates the player's inventory, you're just asking for a `ConcurrentException`